# Java Servlet not working on Tomcat

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, servlets

I have written a Servlet to upload files to the server and store them. As long as I run DevelopmentMode (it's a GWT project) everything works fine. But since I deployed the webapp on Tomcat, the servlet is not even called..

```
public class ImageService extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final long MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 1024; //1GB

@Override
protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response) {

    slog("SERVLET STARTED");

    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

    if (isMultipart) {
        slog("REQUEST IS MULTIPART");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
        try {
            List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator<FileItem> iterator = items.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                FileItem item = iterator.next();

                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String fileName = item.getName();
                    slog("TROVATO FILE " + item.getName());
                    String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
                    File path = new File(root + "/fileuploads");
                    slog("SALVO FILE IN " + path.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (!path.exists()) {
                        path.mkdirs();
                    }

                    File uploadedFile = creaFileNonAmbiguo(path, fileName);
                    slog("NOME ASSEGNATO AL FILE " + uploadedFile.getName());
                    item.write(uploadedFile);
                    response.getWriter().write(uploadedFile.getName() + ";");

                }
            }

            response.getWriter().flush();
            slog("RISPOSTA INVIATA");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    } else {
        slog("LA RICHIESTA NON E' MULTIPART");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
    }   
    slog("SERVLET TERMINATA");
}

@Override
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response) {


    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/").concat(
            "fileuploads/");
    String path = root.concat(request.getParameter("src"));

    File file = new File(path);
    response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
    FileInputStream in;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(file);
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private File creaFileNonAmbiguo(File path, String fileName) {

    File res = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
    if (!res.exists())
        return res;
    else {
        return creaFileNonAmbiguo(path, "c".concat(fileName));
    }
}

private void slog(String s) {
    System.out.println("FILE SERVLET: " + s);
}

}
```

What's wrong with my code? How come it works in devmode and not on Tomcat?

this is my Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

<!-- Servlets -->


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dataLayerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.tesi.server.DataLayerServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dataLayerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/segnalazioni_degrado/dataLayer</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.tesi.server.LoginServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/segnalazioni_degrado/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mailServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.tesi.server.MailServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mailServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/segnalazioni_degrado/mail</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.tesi.server.ImageService</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/segnalazioni_degrado/imageUpload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<!-- Default page to serve -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Segnalazioni_Degrado.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: What happens if you try calling it manually (i.e. typing the servlet url in a browser)?

Comment: @fatman You mean like this? http://localhost:8080/Segnalazioni_Degrado/?imageServlet                  nothing happens.

Comment: yes, what error do you get?

Comment: No errors nor messages nor exceptions..simply nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved it. The problem was, the servlet was mapped to `/segnalazioni_degrado/imageUpload`, while my GWT main module is Segnalazioni_Degrado (capital letters).
Changing the url-pattern made the trick.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, according to your web.xml, the `imageServlet` is mapped to :

```
/segnalazioni_degrado/imageUpload
```

Secondly, you should remove the question mark from the url try changing it to:

```
localhost:8080/Segnalazioni_Degrado/imageUpload
```

and see what happens.

Comment: I get the 404 ERROR message